# Unable to connect to pod using ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod, amazon-eks

I am trying to configure one python flask application running in port 5000 in kubernetes. I have created the deployment, service and ingress. It is not working using the domain name which is added to hosts file, but python application is working when i have tried from port forwarding.

I have tried a lot changing the configurations, but no thing worked.

Please let me know your suggestions.

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: web-app
  namespace: production
  labels:
    app: web-app
    platform: python
spec:
  replicas:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: web-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: web-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: web-app
        image: XXXXXX/XXXXXX:XXXXXX
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web-app
  namespace: production
spec:
  selector:
    app: web-app
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 5000
    targetPort: 5000
  selector:
    run: web-app
```

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: name-virtual-host-ingress
  namespace: production
spec:
  rules:
  - host: first.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: web-app
          servicePort: 5000
```

kubectl get all -n production

```
NAME                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/web-app-559df5fc4-67nbn   1/1     Running   0          24m

NAME              TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
service/web-app   ClusterIP   10.100.122.15   <none>        5000/TCP   24m

NAME                      DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/web-app   1         1         1            1           24m

NAME                                DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/web-app-559df5fc4   1         1         1       24m
```

kubectl get ing -n production

```
NAME                        HOSTS           ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
name-virtual-host-ingress   first.bar.com             80      32s
```

kubectl get ep web-app -n production

```
NAME      ENDPOINTS   AGE
web-app   <none>      23m
```

Comment: Did you set up an ingress controller? If not, the `Ingress` configuration has no effect. If you want to access the app without ingress controller, you can change the type of the `Service` to `nodePort` or `LoadBalancer`

Comment: @rom Is this what you were asking?


kubectl get ing -n production

NAME                        HOSTS                          ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
name-virtual-host-ingress   first.bar.com,second.foo.com             80      32s

Comment: When `kubectl get ep` (or `kubectl describe service`) says `<none>`, that's a sign that the `selector:` on the service doesn't match the `labels:` on the pod (not the deployment, the pod spec inside the template block of the deployment).

Comment: @DavidMaze 

kubectl get pod web-app-deployment-5bc447bfb-2f5v8 -n production -o yaml

`apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2019-06-30T11:06:26Z"
  generateName: web-app-deployment-5bc447bfb-
  labels:
    app: web-app
    pod-template-hash: 5bc447bfb
  name: web-app-deployment-5bc447bfb-2f5v8
  namespace: production
`
It is showing the same web-app label..

Comment: Your service has `selector: {run: web-app}` which doesn't match.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks a lot...... now `kubectl get ep` is showing end points.
But ingress is still not working, i will trouble shoot on that....
Thank you so much....

Comment: Could you please provide the output for: `kubectl describe ingress name-virtual-host-ingress -n production`?

Answer (score 3):

You need to run a Ingress Controller. The Prerequisites part of https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#prerequisites says:

> You must have an ingress controller to satisfy an Ingress. Only creating an Ingress resource has no effect.

One example would be https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/. Be sure to run the **Mandatory Command** and the one that pertains to your provider. You can then get the service to see the assigned IP:

```
kubectl get -n ingress-nginx svc/ingress-nginx
```